# How can get woocommerce SKU with api command

Tags: api, woocommerce, filemaker

My problem:
I need to update a product in Woo commerce over SKU number. But the api of woocommerce has only over product ID. I use json code

My ask:
Can I write a code in body or in link so I can find the product over SKU or update a product over SKU in json programming?

I use postman for these tests.

When I know the ID of the product I use this link
https://www.mydomain.gr/wp-json/wc/v3/products/1361
and in body I write these usually so I will change some product infos.

```
{
   "sale_price": "1050",
   "regular_price":"1100",
  "stock_quantity": "1"   
}
```